# Git running Meld as merge tool fails 'check_requirements import gi'

Tags: git, qt, meld

Error while trying to merge conflicting files:
[image: Error while trying to merge conflicting files]

As version control I use git and I call Meld in order to merge conflicting files. (As IDE I use Qt creator, but I do not think it can be the problem).
I do not understand why the merge procedure fails, because different times this procedure was used in order to merge the projects (the remote and the local one).

Answer (score 9):

The gi module runs, except [it fails to find the GTK DLL](https://github.com/msys2/MINGW-packages/issues/3673):

```
---------------------------
cx_Freeze: Python error in main script
---------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "bin/meld", line 205, in check_requirements
    import gi
  File "C:/msys64/MINGW32/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gi/__init__.py", line 42, in <module>
  File "ExtensionLoader_gi__gi.py", line 23, in <module>
  File "ExtensionLoader_gi__gi.py", line 15, in __bootstrap__
  File "C:/msys64/MINGW32/lib/python3.7/imp.py", line 342, in load_dynamic
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/msys64/MINGW32/lib/python3.7/site-packages\cx_Freeze/initscripts/__startup__.py", line 14, in run
  File "C:/msys64/MINGW32/lib/python3.7/site-packages\cx_Freeze/initscripts/Console.py", line 26, in run
  File "bin/meld", line 362, in <module>
    check_requirements()
  File "bin/meld", line 211, in check_requirements
    missing_reqs("GTK+", gtk_requirement, e)
  File "bin/meld", line 194, in missing_reqs
    show_error_and_exit(_("Cannot import: ") + mod + "\n" + str(exc))
  File "bin/meld", line 182, in show_error_and_exit
    raise Exception(error_text)
Exception: Cannot import: GTK+
DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.

---------------------------
OK   
---------------------------
```

I've added `C:\Program Files (x86)\Meld\lib` to my `Path` [user environment variable](https://superuser.com/a/284351/103551), and now Meld works fine.

Answer (score 4):

I set **meld** as my difftool by executing

```
git config --global diff.tool meld
git config --global difftool.prompt false
```

and I got the same error message.

It took me a while to find https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/meld/issues/282 where Wesley Staples gives a very helpful work-around:

> A temporary workaround is to copy "C:\Program Files (x86)\Meld\lib\libgirepository-1.0-1.dll" to "C:\Program Files (x86)\Meld\libgirepository-1.0-1.dll". Copy it up one directory.

Answer (score 1):

The solution that worked for me is the following

Copy "C:\Program Files (x86)\Meld\lib\libgirepository-1.0-1.dll" to "C:\Program Files (x86)\Meld\libgirepository-1.0-1.dll".

Comment: Please don't forget to cite sources. Did you figure this out on your own, or was it Wesley Staples, here? https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/meld/issues/282